# iOS - Timer invocation issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer, nsinvocation

I wanted to invoke a method if the timer is expired, but the method does not get invoked. Not sure what is going wrong. Any suggestions?

**Being called:**

```
- (void)messageSendingReply:(id)messageID
{
    //Do something.
}
```

**Calling the above:**

```
- (void)sendingMessageTimer_Start:(int64_t)sendingMsgID Time:(NSTimeInterval)replyDelay {

    NSMethodSignature *sig = [self methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(messageSendingReply:)];


    if (sig)
    {

        NSInvocation* invo = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];
        [invo setTarget:self];
        [invo setSelector:@selector(messageSendingReply:)];
        id obj= [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:sendingMsgID];
        [invo setArgument:&obj atIndex:0];
        [invo retainArguments];

        [self.replyTimerDic setValue:[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:replyDelay invocation:invo repeats:NO] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%qi",sendingMsgID]];

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you adding the timer to a run loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by adding the timer on current run loop and run. Thanks.

```
if (sig)
{
    NSInvocation* invo = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];
    [invo setTarget:self];
    [invo setSelector:@selector(messageSendingReply:)];
    id obj= [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:sendingMsgID];
    [invo setArgument:&obj atIndex:0];
    [invo retainArguments];

    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:replyDelay invocation:invo repeats:NO];

    [self.replyTimerDic setValue:timer forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%qi",sendingMsgID]];

    NSRunLoop* runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [runLoop addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    [runLoop run];
}
```